# How do I get my code reviewed if I am owner of Github repository?

Tags: github, pull-request, github-codereviews

I have created a repository(of which I am the owner). My repository has about 5 contributors. We are able to review the code submitted by the contributors when they submit their pull request.

What I need to know is there a way other than me opening another account and becoming a contributor myself to get the changes I commit to the repository be reviewed by other contributors first before they are added to the repo.

Comment: Create a branch, push commits to that branch, create a PR from that branch when ready, ask contributors to review the PR. When the code is reviewed and OK in the branch, merge it to master.

Comment: @JBNizet This should have been answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you always work in a different branch, then you can submit a pull request for merging that branch into master.

If you want *all* branches, and not just master, to be code reviewed, then you will need to work in a different repository. The best way to do this is usually not to open a new account that you make a contributor, but to make an [organization](https://help.github.com/articles/differences-between-user-and-organization-accounts/) for the main repository, [transfer ownership](https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository-owned-by-your-personal-account/) to that, and make your main account a contributor. This is probably better for larger projects but may be overkill for smaller projects.

Either way, you can set the repository to [protect the master branch](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/) and require code review for all commits by everybody (though since you’ll retain control over the repository, you can always bypass this by un-setting that first).

Comment: The note about **protecting the master branch** is what helped me. My branch protection settings for `master` had the **Include administrators** checkbox checked. Once I unchecked that and saved, I was able to squash and merge my pull request, though everything was in red to warn me about it. :-)